# Вынести load в отдельный метод

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('workmenu');
            $this->load->view('all_gk');
            $this->load->view('footer');
```

Вот в этом коде мне не нравится что во всех контролерах мне надо вызывать загрузку хедера, меню, и футера, их можно как то вынести?

Comment: напишите, скажем, хелпер и грузите в нем все. а параметрами отдавайте имя вью и данные. будете делать один вызов

Comment: Не знаю ничего о фреймворке, на котором вы пишите, но иногда лучше в каждом контроллере писать по одной одинаковой строке, чем настраивать наследование, подключать библиотеки, писать костыли и тд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из-за отсутствия layout в Codeigniter, нужно прибегать к костылям.
 Вот решение данной проблемы:
Создается библиотека application/libraries/my_layout.php

```
class MY_Layout extends CI_Controller {

// пути к файлам вида
public $header = 'header';
public $footer = 'footer';

// метод получает на вход два параметра: название вида и данные для него
public function content($views = '', $data = '')
{
    // загружаем header
    if ($this->header)
    {
        $this->load->view($this->header, $data);
    }

    // загружаем основной контент, который может иметь больше одного вида
    if (is_array($views))
    {
        foreach ($views as $view)
        {
            $this->load->view($view, $data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view($views, $data);
    }

    // загружаем footer
    if ($this->footer)
    {
        $this->load->view($this->footer);
    }
  }
}
```

В используемом контроллере достаточно подключить нашу библиотеку и обратиться к нужному виду через $this->my_layout->content('user/test', $data);

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('MY_Layout');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'dynamic_string';
        $this->my_layout->content('user/test', $data);
    }
}
```

Вы так-же можете передавать несколько видов одновременно:

```
$data['title'] = 'dynamic_string';
$views = array(
    'menu' => 'menu',
    'content' => 'user/test'
);

$this->my_layout->content($views, $data);
```

И в завершении, вы можете отключать часть вашего layout'a или использовать вместо него другой вид.

```
$this->my_layout->header = 'user/custom_user_header';
// or turn off header
$this->my_layout->header = FALSE;
```

Пример был взят: [Источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/139875/) . Удачного кодинга...